# Заменить class дочернего пункта меню с помощью hook в Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hook

```
<?php
   $args = array(
     'theme_location' => 'top',
     'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
      )
    wp_nav_menu($args);
?>
```

Натягиваю шаблон bootstrap на wordpress.
Добавляю меню с помощью данного кода.
С помощью `'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'` пунктам главного меню `ul` присваивается класс `nav navbar-nav navbar-right`.
Все отлично, но на дочерние пункты меню это не влияет.
Wordpress по умолчанию присваивает `ul` класс `_sub-menu_`

Можно ли с помощью hook или еще как-то программно заменить класс *sub-menu* на *dropdown-menu* ?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант через *js* `.removeClass('sub-menu')` и `.addClass('dropdown-menu')`

Comment: Отлично, только изучаю wordpress, поэтому интересует решение средствами wordpress